# Quectel BG96 drivers on ubuntu

Tags: driver, modem, quectel

I come to you with questions about Quectel's BG96 drivers installation on Ubuntu. I tried on 14.4, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 but none of these see the BG96 that I plugged into PCi on my PC. I followed the instruction on `https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_WCDMA&LTE_Linux_USB_Driver_User_Guide_V1.8.pdf` but to no avail. Everything stops when I want to issue

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`/drivers/usb/serial obj-m=option.o modules
```

After I issue that command these errors show up

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial' failed
make: *** [_module_/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'
```

And these are the files that I placed into my `/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial/`

option.c

```
static const struct usb_device_id option_ids[]={
#if 1
    { USB_DEVICE(0x2C7C, 0x0296) },
#endif
}

static struct usb_serial_driver option_1port_device = {
#ifdef CONFIG_PM
    .suspend    = usb_wwan_suspend,
    .resume     = usb_wwan_resume,
#if 1
    .reset_resume   = usb_wwan_resume,
#endif
#endif
};
```

usb_wwan.c

```
static struct urb *usb_wwan_setup_urb(struct usb_serial *serial, int endpoint, int dir, void *ctx, char *buf, int len, void (*callback) (struct urb*)){
    usb_fill_bulk_urb(urb, serial->dev, usb_sndbulkpipe(serial->dev, endpoint) | dir, but, len, callback, ctx);

#if 1
    if(dir == USB_DIR_OUT){
        struct usb_device_descriptor *desc = &serial->dev->descriptor;
        if(desc->idVendor == cpu_to_le16(0x2C7C)){
            urb->transfer_flags |= URB_ZERO_PACKET;
        }
    }
#endif
return urb;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find your solution here : https://github.com/bacnh85/Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver

It works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.

there is just some updates, probably because the developper change it's github URL.

```
    git clone https://github.com/bacnh85/Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver.git
    cd Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver
    make
    sudo make install
```